# What is an "ACCESS METHOD"?

Tags: postgresql, index, terminology

In the context of the [`CREATE ACCESS METHOD`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-create-access-method.html) DDL in PostgreSQL,

```
CREATE ACCESS METHOD name
    TYPE access_method_type
    HANDLER handler_function
```

What is a a high level description of what an "access method" is and what they are used for?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexam.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `CREATE ACCESS METHOD` in postgres allows you to define a function to handle (or 'access') a type of index.

It exists to allow you to define new ways for postgres to understand a mapping from the data key values to the actual TID that identifies the related value.

Without an understanding of how relational databases work, it's probably not something you'll ever directly deal with.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "relational databases" in general. This is extremely specific to Postgres an how indexes and their supporting infrastructure are implemented.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's not something inherent to *all* relational databases, but since it deals with indexing of TIDs, you have to understand how a relational database works to properly implement an access method.